# Order barplots in R based on fill value

Tags: r, ggplot2

This problem has been brought up a million times on stacko but I couldn't seem to find a solution that tailored to my particular problem.

I have a data frame which includes a column of species and a column of genome_names:

```
species                  genome_name
Acinetobacter baumannii  Acinetobacter baumanii BIDMC 56 
Acinetobacter baumannii  Acinetobacter baumannii 1032359
Klebsiella pneumoniae    Klebsiella pneumoniae CHS 30
etc...
```

Using this code I created a [barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ND65.jpg) of species with a height of genome_name:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset,aes(x=species,fill=genome_name)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black") + scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) + 
  labs(title="Number of unique strains") +
  labs(x = "Species",y="#Strains") + theme(legend.position="none") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
```

I would like to order this barplot in increasing value of y (number of genome_name). I blindly attempted to do this by putting my data in a factor to no avail:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, del, value = NULL) : 
missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16oHo85Pb8PVX2VqxlqEHizn10H3jVdjRC-kDrELcOfs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you attempted the solutions to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)?

Comment: Here is the exact code copied: ggplot(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset,aes(x=species,fill=genome_name)) + geom_bar(colour="black") + scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) +labs(title="Number of unique strains") +labs(x = "Species",y="#Strains") + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))

Comment: @aosmith yes, that is the factor attempt. I probably am not understanding how to apply his answer to my problem.

Comment: @DanielHarris Did it seem to run for a long time or did it throw the error right away? I am running the code from your comment and it seems to just be running for a long time

Comment: @Hack-R It is a very long run time.

Comment: I'd like to order the species before running ggplot. That way we don't have to run the data for long periods of time.

Comment: Good idea! You can order it like this `PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset[order(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset$species),]`

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks for your time and help! I'll use the code in your answer. It's fantastic.

Comment: Happy to help :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- read.csv("genomes_subset.csv", header = T)
PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- dplyr::sample_n(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset, 300)

PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset[order(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset$species),]


# Order by genome_name
PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- within(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset, 
                   Position     <- factor(genome_name, 
                                      levels=names(sort(table(genome_name), 
                                                        decreasing=TRUE))))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset,aes(x=species,fill=genome_name)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black") + scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) + 
  labs(title="Number of unique strains") +
  labs(x = "Species",y="#Strains") + theme(legend.position="none") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) 

# Order by species
PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <- within(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset, 
                                          species <- factor(species, 
                                                         levels=names(sort(table(species), 
                                                         decreasing=TRUE))))

ggplot(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset,aes(x=species,fill=genome_name)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black") + scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) + 
  labs(title="Number of unique strains") +
  labs(x = "Species",y="#Strains") + theme(legend.position="none") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

This is pretty much the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) but with yours you mentioned ordering it by the fill value, `genome_name`, which is a little different and we also got to see how the ordering affects the run time, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I am getting a error after that first block of code (the factor creation): Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, del, value = NULL) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: @DanielHarris I didn't get that message but it's probably because I sampled the data. What you can do is either (a) use `complete.cases` and exclude the missing values or (b) use either `mean` or `RRF::na.roughfix` to impute the missing values if they are numeric. For missing factor variables either use `addNA` or you can impute them by mode (or exclude the rows with missing values).

Comment: @DanielHarris Here's a little function I wrote to automatically impute missing factor values: `MaxTable <- function(InVec, mult = FALSE) {
  if (!is.factor(InVec)) InVec <- factor(InVec)
  A <- tabulate(InVec)
  if (isTRUE(mult)) {
    levels(InVec)[A == max(A)]
  }
  else levels(InVec)[which.max(A)]
}`

Comment: Is there any way to change the NULLs to NA? I'm not sure I understand the complete.cases solution.

Comment: Cool let me try that.

Comment: Where do I put my data frame or value names in your function? I'm sorry I'm a little confused.

Comment: @DanielHarris If the NULLs are encoded in a way that `is.null` recognizes then you can do `df$var[is.null(df$var)] <- NA` if that doesn't work then you can use `gsub`. BTW if you don't mind could you mark this answer as the solution? :)

Comment: @DanielHarris  `df$my_factor[is.na(df$my_factor)] <- MaxTable(df$my_factor)`

Comment: is.null(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset) returns false. But I'm checking that wrong?

Comment: @DanielHarris Yea you can't use that function on an entire data set in that way. It's just telling you that the entire data set isn't NULL. I would recommend to do this `df$var[is.null(df$var)] <- NA` . You can probably do it against all columns at once by using `apply`, `sapply`, a loop, etc. If you want to check a column do this `table(is.null(df$my_col))`

Comment: I applied PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset <-!is.null(PATRIC_genomes_AMR_2_ris_subset)
and now the first block of code (in your answer) is returning: 
Error in UseMethod("within") : 
  no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: @DanielHarris That's not how `is.null` works ;) so the result you're getting is just a `TRUE` or `FALSE` not your data. I think you were trying to do `my_data <- my_data[!is.null(my_data),]`  Just remember that `is.anything` will always return a logical value, so you use it for indexing or counting but by itself it doesn't return data.

Comment: Actually could I just make an sapply function that sums the number of genome_name per species in a vector. Then use sort(vector, decreasing = TRUE) on that df?

Comment: @DanielHarris Sure, I'm sure you could. Just remember to use `na.rm=T` in the sum / aggregation function when you try it.

Answer (score 1):

reorder the factor levels before ploting:

df$species <- reorder(df$species, df$ge‌​nome_name)

**Edit:**
My bad for not looking at the data more closely.  This plots the number of unique strains sorted by number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(unique_strains = length(unique(genome_name))) %>%
  mutate(species = reorder(species, unique_strains)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(species, unique_strains)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlab(NULL) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: That is returning "> with no change.

Comment: A unique strain can be on more than one line, right?  If that is the case you need to aggregate/summarize before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

To order the bars, set `species` to a factor with the levels sorted by occurrences.

Plotting is taking so long because you're actually drawing a bar for every pair of `species` and `genome_name` that occurs (12,339 of them, to be precise), and stacking the bars by species. If you just want black bars, if you take out the `fill` aesthetic, ggplot can aggregate much more quickly, as it is only drawing one bar per species:

```
# download data
df <- gsheet::gsheet2tbl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16oHo85Pb8PVX2VqxlqEHizn10H3jVdjRC-kDrELcOfs/edit#gid=1638547987')

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(species, names(sort(-table(species)))))) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black") + 
    labs(title = "Number of unique strains") +
    labs(x = "Species", y = "#Strains") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: plot with black bars]

If you plot with a `fill` aesthetic with the same approach, you'll only get black bars anyway, as the `colour` aesthetic set in `geom_bar` is putting a black stroke around each stacked bar, which given how small they are is covering up the filled color. One way to avoid the issue is to simply take out `colour = "black"`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(species, names(sort(-table(species)))), fill = genome_name)) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    labs(title = "Number of unique strains") +
    labs(x = "Species", y = "#Strains") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: plot with colored bars]

If you really want a black stroke on each stacked bar, you'll need to set `size` to something small enough that the fill is not covered by the stroke:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(species, names(sort(-table(species)))), fill = genome_name)) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black", size = 0.01) + 
    labs(title = "Number of unique strains") +
    labs(x = "Species", y = "#Strains") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: plot with colored bars with black stroke]